# Name a dataframe while appending to a list in for loop R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have a bunch of data frames in my global environment with an identical structure (arbitrary label id in column 1, then data in column 2 and 3) that I put in a list `all_dataframes` so that I can loop through them all and divide 1 column by another.  Then I want to save these new dataframes back in the global environment so they they replace their original data frame.  Here's what I have so far.

```
adj_dataframes <- list()

for (i in all_dataframes) {
  i$adj_data <- i$col2/i$col3
  
  j <- i %>%
    transmute(Label_ID,adj_data)
  
  
  adj_dataframes <- c(list(j),adj_dataframes)
}

list2env(adj_dataframes,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

However I get an error message at the `list2env` line because I haven't added any names to the adjusted data frames as they are being added to the `adj_dataframes` list.   How would I be able to essentially get the name of `i` and then add that on/associate it with `j` before `j` is added on to the list? Thanks!

Comment: Is `all_dataframes` named? Can you use `names(adj_dataframes) <-  names(all_dataframes)` right before your `list2env()`?

Comment: Maybe change `adj_dataframes <- c(list(j),adj_dataframes)` to `adj_dataframes <- c(setNames(list(j), i),adj_dataframes)`